# How can I display the full response of an "HTTP Error 429" on Jupyter-Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, http, jupyter-notebook

I'm running an operation on a pandas dataframe that fills in some missing data using a public geo-data api.

```
stops_without_zone_df["ZONE"] = stops_without_zone_df.apply(lambda x : get_geo_data_from_api(x["COORD_X"], x["COORD_Y"])[0], axis=1)
```

The get_geo_data_from_api() function does all the work, fetching and parsing the data, but after a while I get a response 429 from the api:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

This is all the info displayed but a response 429 is usually sent with a "Retry-after" header with the number of seconds until it can receive requests again.

How can I get the full error instead of just a descriptive sentence?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

```
import traceback

try:
    stops_without_zone_df["ZONE"] = stops_without_zone_df.apply(lambda x : get_geo_data_from_api(x["COORD_X"], x["COORD_Y"])[0], axis=1)
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue, I get the stacktrace and some info but nothing on the http response though, thanks anyway @WhiteHat, still learned something.